# Django re_path regex didn't match

Tags: python, django, django-urls

The Django Url pattern didn't match. Can someone tell me why?

This is the re_path:

```
re_path(
    r'^resultcount/(?P<dateiname>.*)_(<int:id>)/$', 
    views.resultcount, 
    name='resultcount'
)
```

I tried with this URL:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/resultcount/Test_(89)

Answer (score 2):

You need to *escape* the parenthesis. Furthermore you can not *mix* `path(..)` syntax and `re_path` syntax:

```
re_path(
    r'^resultcount/(?P<dateiname>.*)_\((?P<id>\d+)\)/$', 
    views.resultcount, 
    name='resultcount'
)
```

The outer parenthesis (with a backslash) are thus parenthesis that are matched by the URL, the inner ones are used to capture the `id` parameter.